# Uninstall mosaico

Tags: civimail, mosaico

I have tried installing mosaico (after installing shoreditch and flexmailer). However it did't work so after searching stackexchange I thought I would install it from github which seems to be a later version than the one you install fromt he extension installer within civicrm. So I disabled and uninstalled. Version 1.0 still apppears on my extensions list, so I deleted the folder from my added extensions folder, and mosaico 1.0 still appears in my extensions page (with the option to install).

How is this possible?!
How do I delete it fully to start again.

I cleared drupal cache and civicrm cache. I'm on CiviCRM 5.9.1 and drupal 7.

Thanks!

Caroline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully delete it, you need to remove the files from your extensions folder.

Then try refreshing the extensions list.

If you do want to install a working version of the extension use version 2.0-BETA4

and the latest versions of Shoreditch theme and Flexmailer.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/mosaico-civicrm-integration/version-20-beta4

Answer (score 1):

The version of Mosaico available from the in-app extensions page is still the old one, so as you have found, if you want the latest version you need to install it manually.

For the old version that you can't remove - expand the entry on the Extensions tab and look for the "Local path" info then check that location.